# Tomcat take request body of previous request as request header in keep alive connection when servlet hasn't read it

Tags: java, http, tomcat, servlets

Tomcat will read request headers fully, but the `POST` body need to be read by `servlet`.

My question is what happens to the request body if the `servlet` send a response without reading it? Discarded or be taken as request header of next request when the connection is `keep alive` for most case of `HTTP/1.1`.

I think it's a bug for `nginx` process this scenario correctly. But I did't found any bug-report in `bz.apache.org`.

What's the supposed behavior in this case for a web-server?

Tomcat version:7.0.55，request body is send with `Content-Length` not `chunked`.

**Background:**

I have two `POST` request both have request body(json string) send using one connection(`HTTP/1.1` with keep alive on default), but the servlet for first request doesn't read request body, `tomcat` take this request body as the next request header, and the client got `HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version Not Supported`. In the access log of tomcat, the request url is the request body, a json string.

```
10.128.8.6 - - [29/Jan/2016:09:47:30 +0800] "POST /action1.do HTTP/1.1" 200 57
10.128.8.6 - - [29/Jan/2016:09:47:30 +0800] "[123]POST /action2.do HTTP/1.1" 505 -
```

Comment: it might be a client bug too -- the requests are not framed corrected. What's the client?

Comment: If you have a legitimate test case, submit it to `security@tomcat.apache.org`. If it requires nginx to be in the mix, it might be a bug in nginx, but for now its more likely to be a configuration error of some kind.

Answer (score 2):

The body is discarded if not read for the processing of the request.

This is nothing to do with Tomcat or servlets, as such, but about the HTTP protocol. The HTTP protocol is stateless, and the behaviour you are asking about would require the server to remember the body of the first request: to hold that information as some state. It also would make no sense to do so: the body of a POST request is unlikely to contain bytes that could be interpreted as a request header.

Tomcat us unlikely to have such a fundamental and damaging bug. If you think you are seeing such a bug, you are probably misinterpreting something.

Comment: Well' it does happened in an incorrectly implementated interface in our production code and gets `HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version Not Supported`